Using macro generated dynamic text as section name
Please see the MWE below. I am extracting some text from a database using a key and then trying to use the extracted text as a section name.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{testkeymatch.csv}
Key,ID,Name
k1,123,John
k2,456,Jane
k3,789,Mary
\end{filecontents}

% Load the CSV data
\DTLloaddb{data}{testkeymatch.csv}

% For key matching
\def\findKeyInfo#1{%
  \xDTLassignfirstmatch{data}{Key}{#1}{%
    % Assign values to temporary macros
    \theID=ID,%
    \theName=Name}%
  % Output the result
  \theID, \theName%
}

\begin{document}

% Extract values for a key
k2: \findKeyInfo{k2}

% \show\findKeyInfo
% \show\xDTLassignfirstmatch

% Use extracted information as section name. This fails
\section{\findKeyInfo{k2}}

\end{document}

While the generated text from \findKeyInfo{k2} is displayed all right, all hell breaks loose when I try to use this text as a section name.

! Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowindex ...@ {#4}\edef \dtl@dogetrowindex 
                                                  {\noexpand \@dtlgetrowinde...
l.38 \section{\findKeyInfo{k2}}


I completely understand that this is due to the fact that while this approach successfully outputs the value to the document, it does not generate a value that we can use as input for another command. In LaTeX, a macro does not return a result; rather, it produces an expansion that includes everything defined within the macro.
So, the \section command argument is something akin to: \protected@edef \@dtl@asg@value {\expandonce {#3}}\expandafter \dtl@a ssignfirstmatch \expandafter {\@dtl@asg@value }{#1}{#2}{#4}.
The above is a set of very complex unexpandable operations.
The \section command requires either a raw value or a macro that can be expanded directly to a raw value without any complexities.
I have struggled (unsuccessfully) with various combinations of \expandafter and \expanded.

This is exactly the same as your previous questions. xstring functions are not expandable, that is why they have the facility to store the result in a specified macro that you can then use in the heading.

applying \expanded or \expandafter to commands that are not expandable will never help.

@DavidCarlisle, where is a xstring command being used here?

oh sorry well yes (in that case why did you load xstring into the example:-) but you are using \xDTLassignfirstmatch which as its name implies is doing assignments so it comes to the same thing. You could use \protected\def\findKeyInfo to make it a robust command so the lookup will be done separately in the section heading, in page headings and the table of contents but doing it once and putting the result in to the section is probably more sensible)

@DavidCarlisle, sorry, copy from historical files. Trying your hints.

@DavidCarlisle, your hint works like a charm.

The following provides a macro that you can use to simplify the extraction of the information. It basically implements for \section what @DavidCarlisle suggested with "putting the result in to the section is probably more sensible".
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.csv}
Key,ID,Name
k1,123,John
k2,456,Jane
k3,789,Mary
\end{filecontents}

% Load the CSV data
\DTLloaddb{data}{\jobname.csv}

\NewDocumentCommand \useWithDTL { m O{\theID=ID,\theName=Name} m }
  {%
    \xDTLassignfirstmatch{data}{Key}{#1}
      {%
        % Assign values to temporary macros
        #2%
      }%
    % use the result
    #3%
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\sectionDTL{m}{\useWithDTL{#1}{\section{\theID, \theName}}}

\NewDocumentCommand\findKeyInfo{m}{\useWithDTL{#1}{\theID, \theName}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% Extract values for a key
k2: \findKeyInfo{k2}

% \show\findKeyInfo
% \show\xDTLassignfirstmatch

% Use extracted information as section name. This fails
%\section{\findKeyInfo{k2}}

\sectionDTL{k2}

\sectionDTL{k1}

\end{document}


I can not tell you how immensely your pointed approach has helped me. In addition to the current problem, this approach solved many of the issues I was struggling with. I am working on a massive project and not all my associates are LaTeX literate. So, I need massive modularity and abstraction. I was using cumbersome techniques in many cases. Your suggestion has hugely streamlined the overall approach.

@Masroor glad I could help and thank you for the positive feedback!

You could use \protected\def\findKeyInfo to make it a robust command so the lookup will be done separately in the section heading, in page headings and the table of contents but doing it once and putting the result in to the section is probably more sensible.

If, due to hyperref being loaded, converting moving arguments of sectioning commands to pdfstrings for bookmarks takes place, then \findKeyInfo occurring within moving arguments of sectioning commands causes trouble due to the underlying non-expandable datatool-macros. Probably an expandable variant of  \DTLfetch would be nice. But I don't see a way for implementing datatool-database-search in a way which is both fast and expandable. So you're probably better off  using datatool's routines for defining scratch macros from values of database entries and laterwards using the scratch macros.
